# What happened to my suggested edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I made a suggested edit to someone else's post. When it hadn't been approved a few hours later I tried to find out whether it was still in the queue or had been rejected, but I couldn't.

Is the ability to check this lurking somewhere I didn't look? If not, I'll resubmit with a feature request.

*(FWIW I now know that it was rejected, but this question is about the general case rather than the specific).*

Comment: Suggested edits are typically reviewed in a matter of minutes, so I'd say if you wait 20-30 min and nothing happens your edit was probably rejected. I don't remember if there's a way to check what happens to pending edits, but the fact an edit existed and was rejected has to be somewhere in the system because reviewers must specify a reason for rejection (i.e. why require one to specify if it's not kept in the system somewhere?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll be able to see the status of your edit by going through the "Suggestions" tab of your recent activity.

That is, go to the "Activity" menu available on your user profile. Click on the tab - "suggestions". Click on the hyperlink that says, "suggested edit". This will tell you if your edit was approved or rejected. Who approved/rejected your edit, and if rejected, the reasons thereof, will be available to you.

While it is easy to know that an edit has been approved (you get 2 points!), I agree that it is hard to know that an edit has been rejected.

[image]

Comment: Curiously the suggested edit I made yesterday isn't listed at all, so I presume that rejected edits vanish after a short time. Thanks.

Comment: @Peter: I'm seeing the info on [this page](http://math.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/4294). I am just as confused as you as to why it does not show up in your activity tab - I can see other users' rejected edits from many months ago appear in the corresponding place on their profiles, for example [the edit here from May 1](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/4929/0-999999999999-9999999999998?tab=activity) (not to single anyone out though).

Answer (score 2):

Suggested edits are visible in your user profile, on the activity tab under "suggestions". Just click on the "suggested edit" link of one entry to get to the suggested edit itself, where it will state whether it was accepted or declined, and by whom.